Multiline legend entry for diagram (pie charts) in QGIS
I have a map with pie charts and I am struggling to format the legend entry for these charts as needed. I know how to wrap "normal" legend entries (add a defined character on which to wrap the text) but it seems not to work for the label of the pie charts in the legend.
Attached you find a screenshot of my unwrapped legend entry and also an example (which was created manually) of how I actually need it (with 3 lines). I'd like to avoid to have to do this manually.
Here is how it looks like:

And this is how I want it to look like (ignore the different values):

